# Python pandas time series dataframe: return only Friday data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe whose index is created by 
pd.bdate_range. The index column consists of business days (Monday through Friday) starting 1993/1/5. The first 12 rows are:

```
df_xx[0:12]
Out[163]: 
               aaa  aaa_f
1993-01-05  125.25    NaN
1993-01-06  124.84    NaN
1993-01-07  125.09    NaN
1993-01-08  125.42    NaN
1993-01-11  125.36    NaN
1993-01-12  125.05    NaN
1993-01-13  125.87    NaN
1993-01-14  125.65    NaN
1993-01-15  126.05    NaN
1993-01-18  125.82    NaN
1993-01-19  125.46    NaN
1993-01-20  125.39    NaN
```

How can I create a subset with only Friday data?

Answer (score 4):

Get names of days by [`DatetimeIndex.day_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day_name.html) and filter DataFrame by[`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
df = df[df.index.day_name() == 'Friday']
print (df)
               aaa  aaa_f
1993-01-08  125.42    NaN
1993-01-15  126.05    NaN
```

Comment: Is it possible to select fortnight Fridays? Example: `2000-01-07, 2000-01-21, 2000-02-04..` and so on? Also, what if the dataframe index is not `datetype`?